# SQL query for Bulk Update

Tags: sql-server, powershell, qsqlquery, sql-query-store

I need to update a table using text file. Currently my code  works fine if I perform `Get-Content` from txt file and then run the SQL update query, but only in case of small data. If the size of text is too long or it contains some special characters, it throws an error as following:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near
')</td><td style=\"border:1px solid #cccccc\">#fieldValueEmpty($issue.getCustom
FieldValue($componentTypeCf),'."
At C:\Users\d-mansings\Desktop\Scripted Field Configuration\Script\Prod_UpdateS
cript.ps1:78 char:37
+     $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Following is the code I'm using:

```bsh
Function DatabaseQueries(){
    #To connect to the SQL database
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$IPSource ; Database=$DBNameSource ; User ID=$UserIDSource ; Password=$LoginPwdSource;"
    $Connection.Open()

    #Query to get the ID of the stored script field from propertyentry 
    $Command1 = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command1.Connection = $Connection
    $Command1.CommandText = "SELECT [ID]    FROM [dbo].[propertyentry] WHERE [PROPERTY_KEY]='com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner:customfields' "
    $Reader = $Command1.ExecuteReader() 
    while ($Reader.Read()) {
        $ID = $Reader.GetValue($1)
    }

    #To get the updated script file
    $ScriptDir = $ParentDir + '\Script.txt'
    $ScriptData = Get-Content "$ScriptDir"
    $Connection.Close()

    #Query to update the Script in JIRA database 
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = @"
    Update [dbo].[propertytext] set [propertyvalue] ='$ScriptData' Where ID=$ID
"@
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()

    $Connection.Close()
}
```

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL-SERVER`?

Comment: What is the contents of `script.txt`?

Comment: Looks to me like you triggered an [SQL injection](https://powershellstation.com/2009/09/15/executing-sql-the-right-way-in-powershell/) vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response, I have figured out a way to execute the query by just using a replace function, as it was getting confused between the single inverted commas

```
select REPLACE(Cast(propertyvalue AS varchar(Max)), '''', '''''') FROM [dbo].[propertytext] WHERE ID=$ID
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to write a complete solution if file contents and database structure are not specified. You surely encountered some kind of SQL injection. SQL Query concatenation is considered harmful and you should avoid it. Use ADO.NET parameters to pass variables (`$Command.Parameters.AddWithValue` in your example). See the following example:

```
function Invoke-Sql(
    $ConnectionString,
    $Query,
    $Parameters
) {
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $ConnectionString
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand -ArgumentList $Query,$conn
    $conn.Open()
    foreach ($arg in $Parameters.GetEnumerator()){
        $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($arg.Key, $arg.Value) | Out-Null;
    }
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if ($reader.Read()) {
      [string[]]$columns = 0..($reader.FieldCount-1) |
          % { if ($reader.GetName($_)) { $reader.GetName($_) } else { "(no name $_)" } }
      do {
        $obj = @{}
        0..($reader.FieldCount-1) | % { $obj.Add($columns[$_], $reader[$_]) }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $obj
      } while ($reader.Read())
    }
    $reader.Dispose()
    $cmd.Dispose()
    $conn.Dispose()
}

Invoke-Sql `
    -ConnectionString "Server=.\SQL2014;Database=Test1;Integrated Security=true" `
    -Query 'SELECT Name, Id [ObjectId], Id + 3, @arg FROM IdNameTest' `
    -Parameters @{arg = 'Some text'''}
Invoke-Sql `
    -ConnectionString "Server=.\SQL2014;Database=Test1;Integrated Security=true" `
    -Query 'UPDATE IdNameTest SET Name=@name WHERE Id=@id' `
    -Parameters @{name = "'DROP DATABASE Death;! %&@!$"; id=1}
```